# Fatal error: Index out of range . Coming near the comment

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell=colView1.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"cell",for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.Image.image=UIImage (named: imagehome[indexPath.row])           //error
    if (collectionView==colView2){
        let cell = colView2.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"cell1", for:indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell2
        cell.Image1.image = UIImage (named: imageHome2[indexPath.row])
        cell.Image1.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.height/2
        return cell
    }
    return cell
}
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: What's the code for numberOfSection & numberOfRows?

Comment: You should check before: `if collectionView == colView1 { ... } else if collectionView = colView2 { ... }` Because you are entering the specific code for `colView2` every time, and if there are more `imageHome2` that `imagehome`, hence the error...

Comment: You need to post the code for your `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` and `numberOfSections(in:)` methods. You also need to move your code that assigns a cell image from `imagehome[indexPath.row]` into your if statement so you don't try to fetch an image from the model for the wrong table view. (If imageHome2 contains more images than imageHome does, your code will crash since it will try to fetch an image from the wrong array.)

Comment: I would advise against writing code that handles the data source for 2 different table views. That's just going to cause you to get confused. Set up two different objects to serve up data for the different table views.

Comment: Sorry, my comments above should have said "collection view", not table view. The comments still apply if you use the appropriate collection view data source methods.

Comment: Do both of your collection views use cells of class `MyCollectionViewCell`?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code to fetch different images depending on which collection view you are providing cells for:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // Change the line below to dequeue a cell from the collection view passed to the function. 
    //(Make sure you have a cell with the identifier "cell" defined for both collection views.)
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"cell",for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    if (collectionView==colView2){
        let cell = colView2.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"cell1", for:indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell2
        cell.Image1.image = UIImage (named: imageHome2[indexPath.row])
        cell.Image1.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.height/2
        return cell
    } else {
        // I moved this line into an else block for the other collection view (colView1?)
        cell.Image.image=UIImage (named: imagehome[indexPath.row])   
        // Do the other setup for a cell from colView1 here.        

    return cell
}
```

Your code is also trying to dequeue cells from colView1 even if the request comes from colView2. That won't work.